Unable to delete a CDC resource in ADF
I had created a CDC resource in ADF to test out, how it works. After few tests, It became non-functional with a red cross mark against it. I cannot edit or view the activity anymore.

If I try to delete the resource, it gives me the below error message.

Could not load resource ''. Please ensure no mistakes in
the JSON and that referenced resources exist. Status: Cannot read
properties of undefined (reading 'tables'), Possible reason: Cannot
read properties of undefined (reading 'tables')

This is also restricting me from setting up Git Configuration or exporting the ARM template, since I am not able to validate that there are no errors in the workspace.
I have tried deleting it using below Python code, but it fails as well.
url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factory_name}/changeDataCaptures/{change_data_capture_name}?api-version={api_version}"

For some reason, I am not able to create a Support ticket with Microsoft to resolve this error.
I would really appreciate any guidance on removing this resource from my ADF.

What is your expected outcome here?

I should be able to delete the cdc resource. It is currently in a limbo state. I cannot edit or view or delete it. This is preventing me to export the ARM template.


Could not load resource ''. Please ensure no mistakes in the JSON and that referenced resources exist. Status: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tables'), Possible reason: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tables')

The reason for above error you are facing is because e of the corrupted json of Change Data Capture Resource you want to delete, and there are missing or incorrect references to tables or other resources. Make sure all referenced resources (like tables) exist and are correctly configured.

Check you have the permissions like Contributor or Owner role assigned to your Azure account with you need to delete the resource Change Data Capture Resource
If any pipelines or activities are utilizing the CDC instance, you may need to stop or delete them before stopping or deleting the CDC instance.
If there are resource locks on the CDC instance it might restrict you to delete the resource.
Try to disable CDC on your Source table and database and then delete the ADF CDC resource it might help you.

-- Disable a Capture Instance for a table
USE MyDB
    EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_table
    @source_schema = N'dbo',
    @source_name   = N'MyTable',
    @capture_instance = N'dbo_MyTable'
    
-- Disable Database for change data capture
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_disable_db

You can check the Azure status page on azure service health to see if there are any ongoing issues or outages that could be affecting you. If still facing issue you need to raise support ticket here.
